# How to add duplicate node in networkx in python

Tags: python, networkx

I want to draw each and every row in the dataframe on networkx in python but due to same node appears twice it is been overwritten is there any way through which i can avoid overridiing.Any help would be of much help thanks in advance
Here is my code to draw networkx in python

my code

```
i = 0
for j in abc:
    G.add_edge(abc[i][0],abc[i][1],weight = abc[i][6])
    G.add_edge(abc[i][1],abc[i][2],weight = abc[i][6])
    G.add_edge(abc[i][2],abc[i][3],weight = abc[i][6])
    i = i + 1

from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 12

elarge=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] >0.10]
emed=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] >0.05 and d['weight'] <0.10]
esmall=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] <0.05]


pos=nx.spring_layout(G) # positions for all nodes

edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=3000,node_color= "grey")



# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=elarge,
                    width=2,alpha = 0.5,edge_color = "b",style = "dashed",edge_labels = edge_labels)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=esmall,
                    width=3,alpha=0.5,edge_color='r',style='dashed')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=emed,
                    width=3,alpha=0.2,edge_color='g',style='dashed')

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,font_size= 12,font_family = "sans-serif")


# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,font_size=12,font_family='sans-serif')
plt.axis('on')
plt.savefig("/home/hduser/Desktop/weighted_graph.png") # save as png
plt.show()
plt.close# displayelarge=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] >0.10]
emed=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] >0.05 and d['weight'] <0.10]
esmall=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] <0.05]


pos=nx.spring_layout(G) # positions for all nodes

edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=3000,node_color= "grey")



# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=elarge,
                    width=2,alpha = 0.5,edge_color = "b",style = "dashed",edge_labels = edge_labels)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=esmall,
                    width=3,alpha=0.5,edge_color='r',style='dashed')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=emed,
                    width=3,alpha=0.2,edge_color='g',style='dashed')

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,font_size= 12,font_family = "sans-serif")


# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,font_size=12,font_family='sans-serif')
plt.axis('on')
plt.savefig("/home/hduser/Desktop/weighted_graph.png") # save as png
plt.show()
plt.close# displayre
```

[dataframe which i am converting to list and then adding its elements to G.add_edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6bpb.png)

[My networkx output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ43g.png)

Comment: Why don't you change slightly the names of the nodes, e.g., name_node+'row_1'?...

Comment: No,I cant because context changes

Comment: It's not abundantly clear what you want the output to look like. Reducing your code to a [mcve] would help. You cannot add duplicate nodes because of what node identity is: each node needs a unique identifier. If the "context changes", then include the context as part of the node ID. But it seems like a graph isn't the best data structure for representing your data.